# Extjs SyntaxError: invalid property id

Tags: extjs4, syntax-error

I have an Edit button, but when I click on it, instead of the Edit User popup window appearing, I get a JavaScript Error, namely 'SyntaxError: invalid property id'. This is what I get when I run in Firefox.

However, when using Internet Explorer, clicking on Edit button generates the following error: 'Microsoft JScript Compilation error: Expected identifier, string or number.' Again, no Edit User popup window appears.

It seems that something is wrong in the way the Edit User popup window is sent back. Tthe code executes and shows the loadMask msg 'Please wait...', but the Edit User popup window is not displayed. Any tips on how to discover/fix the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! The response.responseText returned the Edit User pop up (i.e. the edit.vm file). There was a random % sign in the edit.vm file which was causing the problem.